# Is it possible to modify requests sent by WebView for HTML Offline Caching

Tags: android, android-webview, html5-appcache, offline-mode

I'm using HTML5 Offline cache in a WebView and the resources I try to load are on a webServer that serves different versions based on User-Agent checking.

I can load the website URL in the needed version by specifying the User-Agent with : 
`webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(userAgent);`

But it seems that this setting doesn't apply on requests sent for Application Cache resource retrieval.

Is there any way that allows me to modify requests sent for Application caching ? or at least set the User-Agent header for all requests sent by the WebView ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: that's a bit strange. Which version of Android are you seeing this on?

Comment: I'm testing this on Android 4.4.2 (SDK Api Level 19)

Comment: it's most likely that you've found the bug in the webview. Sorry about that!  I filed a bug here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=360032 and it would be great if you could provide any specific repro steps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer anyway @marcin.kosiba , I'll try to add an archive with both HTML & Android source code to the bugreport you mentionned.

Comment: Is there any workaround for this? Such as setting another http header, or maybe just a way to detect that the request is related to the appcache?

Answer (score 0):

**If you have access to the server** you can use the session to storage the user agent and use it in the next requests. 
The idea is that the first request will contain the correct user agent, but we cant trust in the next request because at least one of then will come from Application Cache and will contain a different user agent.
So a workaround (if you have access to the server) is:

1. Save the user agent into the session during the first access.
2. Use the user agent you saved into the session in all next requests.

Here is piece of PHP code illustrating that.

```
// Get the user agent from the browser.
$userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if (isset($_SESSION['_correctUserAgent'])) {
    // There is already a user agent in the session, so, use it.
    $userAgent = $_SESSION['_correctUserAgent'];
} else {
    // There is no user agent in the session, so, save it for next requests.
    $_SESSION['_correctUserAgent'] = $userAgent;
}
```